# SQL Server 2008: NVarChar(4000)

Tags: sql

For a plain text field, how many characters is nvarchar(4000)?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the motivation for the question? If you need greater length you can use `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: Maybe you're thinking 4000 is bytes?  It's actually the max number of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in sql server 2008, you can also used nvarchar(max), which behaves like a text field, and is not limited to 4000 characters...

Comment: Thats like the text data type?

Comment: its similar, but its varchar, so you can manipulate it like a varchar variable and run string functions, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Varying (up to 4000) as the name suggests!

Comment: yup, i'm guessing author is getting confused by the whole nvarchar uses 2 bytes instead of 1 byte and correlating that with ansi char == 1 byte, so he thinks it will only hold 2000 characters.

Comment: up to 4000 characters, but up to 8000 bytes of space